# Hyperledger fabric - Transaction Workflow

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to understand the Hyperledger Fabric transaction workflow and I don't really understand what happends when the SDK sends a transaction proposal.

The docs say that we can send the transaction proposal into peers who simulate the transaction and return the proposal response, but I don't understand:

1)Who and how do we add these peers in the network?

2)how do we select in which peer to send the transaction proposal?

Answer (score 0):

> 1)Who and how do we add these peers in the network?

Peers should be added to "channel" for processing transaction. Peers are added to specific channel by "operator" or admin of the organization which Peer belongs to.

Channels
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channels.html

> 2)how do we select in which peer to send the transaction proposal?

Client application should know "Endorsement Policy" of the chain code. The endorsement policy describes which organization should endorse the transaction proposal.

Endorsement Policies
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/endorsement-policies.html

Client application picks one of peers in the organization and send transaction proposal.

Answer (score 0):

> 2)how do we select in which peer to send the transaction proposal?

Adding to what Tanaka said correctly above. It is sent to the endorser peers in the channel. We should not (and its not) sent to only one specific peers. if there are lets say 5 endorsers in a channel namely P1...P5, and the endorsement policy is something like 'Sent to P1, P2 and P4. then it will go to these three peers only'.

Sending to only one peer will nullify the concept of how consensus is achieved in the network.

Others can correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1)Who and how do we add these peers in the network?

The component may be organisation or node who has administrative rights can add peers to channel and that are added to network .If peer wants to join network the join request is sent to orderer service node and it will check the channel configuration and approve the join request if the peer is valid i.e., if peer has valid certificate or not.